# Previous employer not happy with review of company

Tags: job-search, employer, review

I wrote a review of a company I worked at on a popular review site.  The review was 100% truthful. I mentioned both the positives and negatives of working at the company. I even said overall, it was a good place to work.  The review was supposed to be anonymous, but somehow the owner knows or suspects it was me, since he wrote me a nasty email saying he did not like the review.

I have no intention of changing the review. I believe people should know what they are getting into. And I'm sure the damage cant be undone.

So how do I deal and explain this to potential jobs in the future? I'm sure the old company will not give me a positive recommendation.

Comment: well... did you deny writing the review? just strongly deny it and say you'd never write that.

Comment: "Oh? I wasn't aware you could review companies on the web! I wouldn't do that to our company though! Wow."

Comment: @insidesin there are a number of them out there, like Glassdoor.com.  Whenever I start to interview for a job, I check out what the employees are saying about the company.  As with any online review site, you have to take the reviews with a grain of salt.  However, it gives you an idea of what you might expect.

Comment: I was giving a short description of how one might feign not taking part in the reviews. Hence the quotes ;)

Answer (score 17):

First, there is no such thing as anonymity.  The more information you divulge in a review the easier it is to identify the exact person who posted it.

Second, you have to weigh the consequences of your speech.  Sure, you can write whatever you want in a review but there may be negative consequences for doing so.  Obviously you are now running into some of those consequences.  I'm not going to tell you to change or remove your review as that's a personal decision.  Rather I'm just going to say that you should think about this before posting too much information if you decide to do it again in the future.

You've now burned a bridge.  Although you need to list that employment on your resume, I wouldn't try to use them as a reference.  Depending on what country you are in that employer may not even be contacted with regards to your work history.  And even if they are, hopefully only HR will be contacted and not the owner that way this specific problem is "forgotten" about.

Which leads to the next thing - it's incredibly unlikely that a future employer will question you about things that pop up during their due diligence on you.  Which means it's unlikely you'll have an opportunity to explain yourself.

My advice is simply to not worry about it until it comes up.  If it does then honestly answer their questions.

Answer (score 12):

> So how do I deal and explain this to potential jobs in the future?

I suggest you ignore the nasty email he sent and carry on with your life and job-hunting.

Don't know what damage you could have caused by posting an anonymous review, besides the one done to the owner's ego. If he plans to say negative things about you because of this situation that would be unprofessional from *his* part; your true performance there is still unchanged.

**If** future recruiters ask you for your reasons for leaving you should tell such reasons truthfully. I am sure there are other former coworkers of yours that could refute the negative statements made by the owner in case he really took this as a personal vendetta, but you should worry about that only when the time comes.